Text value in Sumifs / DATEVALUE
How do I have to change the formula so that it can handle text values?
 COLUMN A    COLUMN B

18.05.2024 | 3.202,39€
14.01.2024 | 2.138,32€
04.05.2024 | 1.292,99€
10.01.2024 | 2.952,80€
22.06.2024 | 3.184,11€
01.06.2024 | 1.267,29€


C1  =SUMIFS(B1:B;A1:A;">="&DATEVALUE("2024-01-01");A1:A;"<="&DATEVALUE("2024-01-31"))
C1  = 0,00 €

A and B must remain text !!!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19RFXUWy32DNR6QhpkoTbt7ZU_FjLHdApD_OZWS3lO-I/edit?usp=sharing


You may try:
=sum(ifna(filter(--B:B;eomonth(--substitute(A:A;".";"/");)=eomonth(date(2024;1;1);))))


